# Braid group relations

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, knot-theory, group-presentation

The braid group on $n$ strands, denoted $B_n$, has a geometric/topological definition as the group whose elements are equivalence classes of $n$-braids (under ambient isotopy), and whose group operation is composition of braids. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group) for more details.

The standard presentation of the braid group $B_n$ is $$\langle \sigma_1,\ldots, \sigma_{n-1}\mid\sigma_i \sigma_{i+1}, \sigma_i=\sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1} \text{ for }1\leq i\leq n-1, \text{ and } \sigma_i\sigma_j=\sigma_j\sigma_i \text{ for } |i-j|\geq 2\rangle.$$

Geometrically we can verify that these relations indeed hold, and so $B_n$ is a homomorphic image of the group with this presentation. But how do we know if these are all the possible relations there can be?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "if these are all the possible relations"? Defining a group in this way is saying that the given relations are the only relations which hold.

Comment: Taking the definition of $B_n$ from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group) (see also the picture) we have " It can be shown that all other relations among the braids 
$\sigma _{1},\ldots ,\sigma_{n-1}$ 
already follow from these relations and the group axioms."

Comment: There's no such thing as *the* presentation of a group; there are infinitely many. Just apply Tietze transformations.

Comment: @Dietrich my interpretation of the question is "why are these the only relations?". That is: it's easy to prove that the braid group is a quotient group of the group with this presentation, but why does the other direction hold? Or to put it another way: *how can we show* that all other relations among the braids $\sigma_1,\ldots, \sigma_{n−1}$ already follow from these relations and the group axioms?

Comment: @user1729 Yes, this is also my interpretation. It can be shown. I did not check yet the references at Wikipedia.

Comment: @Dietrich Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. The Wikipedia article just says that it can be shown, but does not prove it.

Comment: @user1729 Yes that was my question. Sorry if I didn't formulate it very clearly.